# I am trying to call a php file on click of button using ajax ,jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am just started learning the basics of jquery and ajax.I have already tried for this problem.also check the previous answers of Stackoverflow.but that code does not work.I have create two pages contains index.php and testing.php.and my button is in index page.when i am clicK on button ..then the button not work also not pass to  testing.php .here i am using jQuery and ajax function

HTML file(index.php)

```
<input type='submit' name='Result' value='Show Graph' id='Result' onclick='return go_graph();'/>
```

Here i am also trying to call on Javascript.also nt working.

jQuery File

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        alert(projectID);

        $('#Result').click(function(){
            var clickBtnValue = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                url: "testing.php?projectID="+projectID+"&clickBtnValue="+clickBtnValue,
                success: function(results){
                    res=results;
                    alert ('haii');
                },
            });
        });

        function go_graph(){
            alert(projectID);
            $.ajax({
                url: "testing.php?projectID="+projectID,
                success: function(results){
                    res=results;
                    alert(res);
                },
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have syntax error in ypur `$.ajax` Check this out

```
$.ajax({
    url:"test3.php?projectID="+projectID+"&clickBtnValue="+clickBtnValue,
   success:function(results){
     res=results;
     //alert(res);
     alert ('haii');
    } //was missing
    });

  });
 });
```

Also change this `<input type='submit' name='Result' value='Show Graph' id='Result' onclick='return go_graph();'/>`
to
 `<input type='button' name='Result' value='Show Graph' id='Result' onclick='return go_graph();'/>`

Compete code

```
 <input type='submit' name='Result' value='Show Graph' id='Result' onclick='return go_graph();' />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var projectID = 1;
  alert(projectID);
  $('#Result').click(function(){
  var clickBtnValue = $(this).val();
  $.ajax({
    url:"testing.php?projectID="+projectID+"&clickBtnValue="+clickBtnValue,
   success:function(results){
     res=results;
     //alert(res);
     alert ('haii');
    }
    });

  });
 });
 function go_graph(){

    alert('go');
     $.ajax({url:"testing.php?projectID="+projectID,
    success:function(results){
     res=results;
     alert(res);
     }

  });

    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanku @Miss Chetan Gawai

Answer (score 0):

Use return:

```
success:function(results){
     res=results;
    return res;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function go_graph()
{

    alert(projectID);
     $.ajax({
      url:"testing.php,
      data:projectID="+projectID,
    success:function(results){
     res=results;
     alert(res);
     }

  });

    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to asynchronously run the php files using AJAX and get the response? If so, try calling the preventDefault() method in your jQuery click event handler.

```
$('#Results').click(function(event){
event.preventDefault();
//rest of your code goes here
});
```

This would prevent submission of the form and the AJAX call will asynchronously return the response generated by the php files.